# Sound Card Creating Mic Static

Tags: microphone, sound, problems

I am using a generic karaoke microphone with a C-Media Pci sound card (an older one). If I enable playback, (you can hear what your mic is recording) I hear copious amounts of static. I can find no software or setting to ease the static. I can live with some static, it's just something that will happen, given the quality of my hardware, but the static is generally significantly louder than any actual noise from the mic. Also, the static seems to be coming from/caused by the sound card because it is still present even when I unplug the mic entirely. Is there anything I can do about this? Hopefully without having to replace my hardware. I am running a 64 bit version of Windows 7. All help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure it is the mic input and not the headphone output? is the static only there with playback enabled?

Comment: Are you monitoring with headphones or through speakers?